# Django Action Dynamic reporting from admin

Tags: django, admin

I am trying to create a drop down action with in the django admin page that redirects the user to a report page of all the selected entries.

```
class Device(models.Model):
        id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
        phoneName = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        Model = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        PhoneNumber = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        OSVersion = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

So I have a page built out, but I don't understand how to make the admin action redirect the user to the page.

Can someone provide me a little direction? Ideally I'd like to be able to say, display a list of all ids and their respective phone numbers, on one report then hopefully with very little add I can say hey show me the OS and Model report. But that can be two separate drop downs.

Thank you,
Jeremy

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I found the piece of code I was missing.

```
model_class = ContentType.objects.get(id=request.GET['ct']).model_class()
device_list = model_class.objects.filter(pk__in=request.GET['ids'].split(','))
```